# How to use Accordion under <td> tag? Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html-table, accordion

I have a table , when I will click on any of row when a new table should be stretched under the same  . I tried to use accordian of ngx-bootrap but I failed. 

**Basically I need a expandable table inside table. When I will click to any of row I will call a service which will give data for expanding table.**

[image]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fjykowtL/2/ check this example

Comment: Example is good but facing bootstrap related issue as I am using ngx-bootstrap, also the example is in JS instead of TS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to get the same table. 
**sample.component.html**

```
 <table class="table">
            <tbody>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let item of topItem; let i = index">
                <tr>
                  <td width="5%" (click)="toggle(item, i)">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-{{ i }}-icon" [ngClass]="{'fa-expand-icon': visible,'fa-compress-icon': !visible}"
                    ></i>
                  </td>
                  <td width="20%">{{ item.Name }}</td>
                  <td width="15%">{{ item.mobile }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="d-none row-num-{{ i }}">
                  <td *ngIf="showTable" colspan="2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <table class="table">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let item of subsItem; let i = index">                              
                              <td>sample data</td>
                              <td>sample data</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </ng-container>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Use typescript file **sample.component.ts**

```
toggle(item, index) {
    let selector = `.row-num-${index}`;
    document.querySelector(selector).classList.toggle('d-none');
    this.showTable = true;
  }
```